# Mongo : How to Display User Specific Data From 2 Different Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to Display User Specified data.i use Passport for authenticate User and  I have 2 Database name :

- users
- tasks

  In Users there are : Username, Email, password Fields
  And in Tasks i have : startTime, endTime, sessionTime,Email
  so i only want to Display data which is matched with email or is there any other way to identify user specific data to Display

My Get Req Code :

```
router.get('/show', (req, res, next) => {
    Task.find({})
        .exec(function (err, task) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    Message: "Error in Getting Task",
                    Error: err
                })
            }
            res.json(task)
        })
})
```

is there any way to get only user specified data

or can i do some change in passport code to display specific data
Passport Code:

```
   function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.isValid(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man if email from usar and email from tasks are exactly equals you can use `aggregation framework` from mongo DB

Using aggregation framework with NodeJS:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/aggregation/

Using lookup (inner join equivalent):
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "tasks",
         localField: "email",
         foreignField: "pEmail",
         as: "Tasksss"
       }
  }
])
```

This may Helps You